# Implementing "disabled" concept of custom element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, lit-element

Is there a built in way to handle the concept of a *disabled* control is the web components spec and/or lit-element?

Based on Google the answer is no, so I've implemented it from scratch. I feel like this should already be "solved for", is there a simpler way?

```
@customElement('x-input')
export class CustomInput extends LitElement {
  static shadowRootOptions = {
    ...LitElement.shadowRootOptions,
    delegatesFocus: true
  };
  
  static styles = css`
    div { border:1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
    div:focus { border-color: red; outline: 0; }
    :host([disabled]) div { background: grey; }
  `;
  
  @property({ type: Boolean, reflect: true })
  public disabled: boolean = false;
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    // set the control as focusable by default
    this.tabIndex = this.tabIndex < 0 ? 0 : this.tabIndex;
    // to prevent focus on click
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", this._onMouseDown);
  }
  
  render() {
    return html`<div contenteditable tabindex=${this.disabled ? -1 : 0}>`;
  }
  
  private _onMouseDown(e: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.disabled) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Full playground: [link](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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_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-XG4gIDx4LWlucHV0PjwveC1pbnB1dD5cbiAgPHgtaW5wdXQgdGFiaW5kZXg9XCIxXCI-PC94LWlucHV0PlxuICA8eC1pbnB1dCBkaXNhYmxlZD48L3gtaW5wdXQ-XG4gIDx4LWlucHV0IHRhYmluZGV4PVwiMVwiPjwveC1pbnB1dD5cbiAgPHgtaW5wdXQ-PC94LWlucHV0PlxuPC9ib2R5PlxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoicGFja2FnZS5qc29uIiwiY29udGVudCI6IntcbiAgXCJkZXBlbmRlbmNpZXNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwibGl0XCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJAbGl0L3JlYWN0aXZlLWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMS4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjMuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtaHRtbFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiXG4gIH1cbn0iLCJoaWRkZW4iOnRydWV9XQ).

**Edit:** I'm probably missing something to handle when the disabled flag switches from `false -> true`, will need to call `this.blur()`...but the question is still valid.

Comment: Since a Web Component can be/do anything, how can standard code know how to disable _anything_? Maybe the 'new' (not yet in FireFox) [HTML attribute ``inert``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert) can help. Monitoring your ``disabled`` attribute is done with the MutationObserver API

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - does make sense, was kinda expecting there to be a Mixin out there that I haven't found

Comment: Not really sure what you want to do here. But if you goal is to prevent users from focusing on the div whenever the :root is disabled, then maybe you just need to add `:root([disabled]) { pointer-events: none }`. There may also be some accessibility issues with this.